# How can i enable only TLSv1.2 on my REST api

Tags: https, mule, tls1.2

I have an API on which I have to enable only TLSv1.2 . Following is the configuration I have where i have set enabledProtocols="TLSv1.2".

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTPS_api-httpListenerConfig"
        protocol="HTTPS" host="0.0.0.0" port="${https.port}" 
        doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">
    <tls:context enabledProtocols="TLSv1.2">
        <tls:trust-store insecure="true" />
        <tls:key-store type="pkcs12" path="${keystore.pkcsstore}"
            alias="${keystore.alias}" keyPassword="${keystore.password}"
            password="${keystore.password}" />
    </tls:context>
</http:listener-config>
```

Now when I deploy it in my local and try to consume it with the following client it works fine . unfortunately , when i deployed the same in cloudhub and try to consume it, its giving me following error even though i have explicitly set TLSv1.2 to use from client:

SSL handshake error: Client requested protocol TLSv1.1 not enabled or not supported

request config :

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration_basicAuth"
     host="testtlsversion.cloudhub.io" port="443"
     doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS"
     responseTimeout="9999999">
     <tls:context enabledProtocols="TLSv1.2">
         <tls:trust-store path="${alert.keystore.path}" password="${alert.keystore.password}" type="jks" insecure="true"/>
     </tls:context>
 </http:request-config>
```

Comment: Please cross check the error comes for  this http-request config `HTTP_Request_Configuration_basicAuth`. Have you enabled  this configuration `TLSV1.2` for all other http-request?

Answer (score 0):

TLS V1.2 is not supported in current version .

Answer Here :https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/84103/how-can-i-enable-only-tlsv12-on-my-rest-api.html?childToView=84150#answer-84150